# How to make the camera look at a specific child in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm using THREE v0.86 with React and I'm to trying to get the world position of a specific child of a parent, so when I click a button I can change its material color and make the camera face to it.

First, I store a reference for each of the children I'm interested, on the onLoad function:

```
const onLoad = object => {

      object.name = "scene 1";
      object.position.set(0, 5, 0);
      obj3d.add(object);
      object.traverse(
        function(child) {
          if (condition === true) {
            let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });
            child.material = material;
            this[child.name] = child; // <-- Here
          }
        }.bind(this)
      );
    };
```

Then, I've tried it two ways: first **with** controls enabled: TrackballControls

```
moveCamera(selectedChild) {

    this[selectedChild].material.color.setHex(0xff0000);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#FF0000" });
    this[selectedChild].material = material;

    const newPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    newPosition.setFromMatrixPosition(this[selectedChild].matrixWorld);

// I've tried this:
    this.controls.target = this[selectedChild].getWorldPosition();

// OR this
    this.controls.target = newPosition;

    this.camera.lookAt(this[selectedChild]);
  }
```

Also, I've **disabled** the controls and tried this:

```
moveCamera(selectedChild) {

    this[selectedChild].material.color.setHex(0xff0000);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#FF0000" });
    this[selectedChild].material = material;

    this.camera.lookAt(this[selectedChild].getWorldPosition());
  }
```

With this in the renderScene() function:

```
renderScene() {
    this.renderer.autoClear = true;
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xfff0f0);
    this.renderer.setClearAlpha(0.0);
    this.scene.updateMatrixWorld(); // <- THIS

    if (this.composer) {
      this.composer.render();
    } else {
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

  }
```

The `moveCamera(childName)` does change the specific child color but the problem is that it **ALWAYS** looks in the same direction, so I consoled log the parent object and took a glance at the children and they all have the same `matrix`, `matrixAutoUpdate: true`, `matrixWorld`, `matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false` properties values between them and they are all the parent's values as well, so of course the `newPosition.setFromMatrixPosition(this[selectedChild].matrixWorld);` vector will always be the same. What am I missing? why aren't the different children objects positions relative to the world different?

This is my scene setup

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { THREE, innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;

    OBJLoader(THREE);
    MTLLoader(THREE);

    this.setScene();
    this.setCamera();
    this.setRenderer();

    this.group = new THREE.Group();
    this.selectedObjects = [];
    this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    this.enableControls();

    this.start();
  }
```

Where:

**this.setScene()**

```
setScene() {
    const { THREE } = window;
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.002);

    // LIGHTS
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xaaaaaa, 0.2));
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xddffdd, 0.6);
    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
    const d = 10;
    light.shadow.camera.left = -d;
    light.shadow.camera.right = d;
    light.shadow.camera.top = d;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;
    scene.add(light);

    const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.5);
    hemiLight.color.setHSL(0.6, 1, 0.6);
    hemiLight.groundColor.setHSL(0.095, 1, 0.75);
    hemiLight.position.set(0, 500, 0);
    scene.add(hemiLight);

    // GROUND
    const groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000, 1000);
    const groundMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xffffff,
      specular: 0x050505
    });
    groundMat.color.setHSL(0.095, 1, 0.75);

    const ground = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, groundMat);
    ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    ground.position.y = -0.5;
    scene.add(ground);

    // SKYDOME
    const vertexShader =
      "varying vec3 vWorldPosition; void main() { vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz; gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); }";
    const fragmentShader =
      "uniform vec3 topColor; uniform vec3 bottomColor; uniform float offset; uniform float exponent; varying vec3 vWorldPosition; void main() { float h = normalize( vWorldPosition + offset ).y; gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( bottomColor, topColor, max( pow( max( h , 0.0), exponent ), 0.0 ) ), 1.0 ); }";
    const uniforms = {
      topColor: { value: new THREE.Color(0x0077ff) },
      bottomColor: { value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff) },
      offset: { value: 0 },
      exponent: { value: 0.6 }
    };
    uniforms.topColor.value.copy(hemiLight.color);

    scene.fog.color.copy(uniforms.bottomColor.value);

    const skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(300, 32, 15);
    const skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      vertexShader: vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
      uniforms: uniforms,
      side: THREE.BackSide
    });

    const sky = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeo, skyMat);
    scene.add(sky);

    this.scene = scene;
  }
```

**this.setCamera**

```
setCamera() {
    const { THREE, innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      45,
      innerWidth / innerHeight,
      0.1,
      100
    );
    camera.position.set(-4.1, 7.2, 4.2);
    this.camera = camera;
  }
```

**this.setRenderer**

```
setRenderer() {
    const { THREE, innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
    renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight * this.windowMultiplier);
    this.renderer = renderer;
  }
```

**this.start this.stop this.animate**

```
start() {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  }

  stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
  }

  animate() {
    this.renderScene();
    this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    if (!!this.controls) {
      this.controls.update();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! All of my code works perfectly, the problem was in the .obj itself, all of the children's pivot points where the same as the parent, they weren't at the object's center (how one would expect):

[image: Here you can see the highlighted object (a child) and its pivot point (same as the parent, which is wrong)]

Answer (score 0):

The Object3D [`.lookAt`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.lookAt) method expects a position in world space:

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3().copy( child.position );
child.localToWorld( position );
camera.lookAt( position );
```

Using TrackballControls or OrbitControls would complicate this, I'm not sure whether `lookAt` will work properly with either of those involved.

three.js r89

Comment: this does the same as what I wrote because it's using one the child's matrix for position (I'm guessing `matrixWorld`), the main problem is that all the children and the parent have the same values for their matrixes, and I'm not sure why.

Also, no, `lookAt` won't work with those controls, that's why I disable them if I'm using it.

Comment: Would you be able to create a JSFiddle reproducing the problem? Here's [a live example](https://codepen.io/donmccurdy/pen/zWrEgQ?editors=1010) showing `.lookAt` with a transformed parent, which does work as expected.

Comment: The thing is, `.lookAt` works perfectly, it is doing what it should. See, if I `console.log(parent.getWorldPosition())` and `console.log(child.getWorldPosition())` they're the same! And happens with all the children, that's why it will always look at the same spot, regardless what I pass to the `moveCamera()` function.

Comment: The problem is that your question does not show what your scene's structure is, or how to reproduce it. So I can't guess what parent/child positions should be or are. Also — it looks like you're passing an _object_ into `lookAt`, rather than a position?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to the `.getWorldPosition()` to the object in the `.lookAt`, added it. I am loading a Unity made scene and then I am setting a reference to certain children, but, anyway, shouldn't the `.getWorldPosition()` always be different?? The parent as an object holds a position within the 3D world, but the children hold another one each, how could `.getWorldPosition()` be returning the same vector (the parent's initial position) for all the objects? (I'll add the scene setup)